# Access modifiers on property getters

Tags: oop, properties, access-modifiers

For specific context, I develop in C#, but I suppose this could be applied to other languages/frameworks.

I understand that creating a property with a private getter and a public setter is perfectly legal:

```
public int MyInt { private get; set; }
```

I'm having trouble figuring out why one would want to allow a client to set a property without being able get its current value.  Under what circumstances might this type of behavior desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the 'client' which changes the value, it's other parts of the program.

It's possible that you want other objects have the ability to change the state of an object, via that property.
The other parts of the object don't *care* for the state of that object however, it's kept for internal logic only.

It all depends on the case and the structure of your application.

Comment: Okay... maybe "client" is the wrong word.  I'm looking for "whoever uses the object."  Secondly, I was looking for a situation (maybe an example) of an object that wants to blindly set a property on another object and never retrieve it.

Comment: @gregsdennis: For example, I may want to instantiate a database connection object, with a username and a password. But those credentials must never be revealed. They can be set by the responsible object, but should never be accessed. The details are used only by the internal object logic.

Comment: great example.  Thanks.  My curiosity has been quenched.